# I need to rebuild my entire solution to get the Visual Studio Test Explorer to notice changes

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

As the title says. After making changes to a test I can't seem to get the Test Explorer to notice these changes without rebuilding the entire solution. Since this takes about 20 minutes it is not very practical.

I have tried with a simple demo project and it seems to work fine for that but doesn't work with our codebase.

I have read quite a few useful questions concerning Visual Studio so there seem to be some people who are knowledgeable in that regard. If anybody has any ideas what I could try or check they would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try Resharper test runner. Seems to be much faster than the built-in Test Explorer

Comment: I know it's almost weird but I don't have Resharper. :)

Comment: It's helpful. I have a project where it would take 5-7 mins for the test explorer to discover tests. Resharper does this instantly. Also, if you say 20 minutes - is it really building or discovering the tests? One of my colleagues had an idea to create a test list (or something along this lines) so that the discovery is not needed. I don't know if it is possible in VS2012 but I remember it was there in VS2010. I decided to move to Resharper and have not tried that. (you may also want to check test driven .net)

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed in Visual Studio 2013 update 2:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/809777/running-a-single-unit-test-in-visual-studio-2013-causes-entire-solution-to-be-built

I was experiencing the same problem and have just upgraded from VS 2013 Update 1 to Update 4. I can confirm I can now run single unit tests via the Test Explorer without rebuilding my entire solution.